# Проблема с отражением SeekBar

Tags: android-constraintlayout, seekbar

Недавно начала изучать `Android Studio` и никак не могу решить проблему с отражением `SeekBar` при запуске приложения на телефоне. В `Android Studio` у всех `View` настроены `Constraint Widget` и на вкладке `Design` я вижу `SeekBar`, но когда запускаю приложение на телефоне, то вижу все `View`, кроме самого `SeekBar`. Куда он девается никак понять не могу!

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="158dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewLogoCircle" />
```